How can I implement a CR process When I push my local branch to my remote branch [The branch is same but one is local other is remote]
Eg:
here is a branch named test.
I pull it down to my local and change something.
and I commit the change then push it to remote.
I need add a code review verification before I push to remote.
More specifically, I want the work flow like this:
change local branch test -> commit -> push -> someone review my code on github (I need this one!!!) -> change remote branch test.
Can I do this using github simply?

On Github, the concept of review is tied to a Pull Request, not to a push.
If you want to have someone review your changes, you will have to open a PR.
One way you could add this control gate is to:

Introduce changes to the test branch through PRs. This means branching off of test every time you want to change something
Introduce a GitHub action that runs on every PR that attempts to merge to test, specifically with

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - test


Optionally go to the Github repository's settings --> branches --> test and enable a branch protection rule with "Require a pull request before merging" and "Require approval". This way you can automatically enable auto-merge from inside the workflow, see here, and the PR will automatically be merged to test once the review passes.

If you really don't want to have to open a PR manually every time, you could do this:

Create another branch directly off of test, say test-non-reviewed, and push directly to it.
Add a workflow that runs every time something is pushed to that branch and automatically opens a PR to merge that to test. It could look something like

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test-not-reviewed

jobs:
  merge-branches:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: test-not-reviewed
          fetch-depth: 0 # Fetch all history for all branches and tags.

      - name: Set Git identity
        run: |
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions"
          git config user.email "github-actions@github.com"

      - name: Start the merge
        run: |
          git checkout test
          git merge origin/test-not-reviewed

      - name: Open PR test-not-reviewed --> test
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v6
        id: openPR
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          commit-message: "Auto-merge to test branch"
          title: "Auto-merge to test branch"
          branch: auto-merge/to-test
          base: test

      - name: Enable Auto-merge
        if: ${{ steps.openPR.outputs.pull-request-operation == 'created' || steps.openPR.outputs.pull-request-operation == 'updated' }} # Only enable automerge if PR creation succeeded
        run: gh pr merge --merge --auto "${{ steps.openPR.outputs.pull-request-number }}"
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_GITHUB_TOKEN }}

This opens the PR automatically. The whole auto-merge stuff is only available if you have branch protection rules active that require reviews and/or checks to pass, you decide if you need it.
Note that for some of these actions you will need to add your PERSONAL_GITHUB_TOKEN to the repository's secrets.
